why pycharm couldn't retrieve package description
I use the Pycharm.
when I use the 'python packages' to install a libaray, it shows
'Couldn't retrieve package description.It can still be installed.'
even I can install ,but I can not see the description.who could help me?
thank you
enter image description here
what should I do? thank you

Have you tried the pip install command to install the packages you want using the terminal.

Same here, did you resolve?
